# Sorting by date and id but numbers are not in ascending order

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I have one jQuery Datatable. All is working fine except default sorting. I'm using PHP server-side script and have using this parameters:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
   'bAutoWidth': false,
   'bServerSide': true,
   'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
   'aaSorting': [[ 2, 'desc' ]],
   'sAjaxSource': './table/myscript.php'
});
```

So my page shows data table correct, using second column for sorting (which is by date because I edited cfg file) and now my ID in datatable is not in ascending order.

Numbers for example:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

It is this order:

```
8
11
10
7
6
5
4
3
2
9
```

What i need to put in datatables initialization parameters to sort by column 2 and ID that will be in ascending order?

Comment: Show a data JSON segment so we can see what you are sorting here...

Comment: Are you trying to sort by date and then by ID?

Comment: I need to sort only by date(2 row) and want when sort is done by date that ID will be ASC order...do you have idea what i need to do? I im using php script in server side